# Selectpicker val multiple select via data in function

Tags: jquery, datatable

I cant seem to select multiple options after calling a function (onlick= edit_data). It works when the values is passed manuelly, however when the function is getting the info from a variable its not working.

Here is the function

```
function edit_data(invoker,id){
    $('#gls_zones input[name="id"]').val($(invoker).data('id'));
    $('#gls_zones input[name="name"]').val($(invoker).data('name'));

    var countries = $(invoker).data('countries');

    $('#countries').selectpicker('val', [countries]);
    $('#countries').selectpicker('refresh');

    $('#gls_zones').modal('show');
}


<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="#" onclick="edit_data(this,7); return false;" data-id="7" data-name="Zone 1" data-countries="22,83,128,155">Zone 1</a></td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uz1Ln7xf/9/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you supply an example illustrating you problem? It must be possible to do in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uz1Ln7xf/8/

Comment: Please clarify:  a) what does it means "however when the function is getting the info from a variable its not working", b) `onclick=edit_date` - you mistyped `edit_data`?, c) https://jsfiddle.net/r87cnf5w/1/ - is this edited fiddle is correct?

Comment: Oooh yes, mistyped edit date in the description

Comment: And fiddle is correct

Comment: Multiselect works fine for me using `ctrl+lmb`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azaviruha/skx9yu6m/5/) solve your problem?

The problem with your script is that your `edit_data` gets a global object (window) as `invoker`.